# Can every positive integer be a divisor of this sum?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, divisibility

Define $$f(n):=\sum_{j=1}^n j^{j+1}=1+2^3+3^4+\cdots +n^{n+1}$$

> Does for every integer $p\ge 2$ exist a positive integer $n$ with $p\mid f(n)$ ? In other words, can every positive integer be a divisor of $f(n)$ ?

I used this simple sieve in PARI/GP :

```
? x=[2..10^4];n=1;s=1;while(length(x)>0,n=n+1;s=s+n^(n+1);y=select(a->Mod(s,a)==0,x);if(length(y)>0,x=setminus(x,y);print(n,"   ",length(x))))
```

to determine upto which $\ n\ $ we must continue to cover all divisors upto $\ p=10^4\ $

Last line in the output is

```
69696   0
```

Hence every positive integer $p\le 10^4$ can be a divisor and we need not go beyond $\ n=69696\ $. The toughest divisor is $\ 8549\ $

Comment: $p$=10274 divides $f(70416)$

Comment: $p=11414$ divides $f(80128)$

Comment: How did you get the question? Is it a part of some work you are doing. I am just curious to know the context!

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA No, I began a factorization project in which I try to factor numbers of this form. It is purely recreational.